# NotificationManager.notify() fails with SecurityException

Tags: android, permissions, wakelock, android-wake-lock, notificationmanager

When does `NotificationManager.notify()` require `WAKE_LOCK` permission on Android 2.2?

I received following stack trace from one user:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user ***** nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
  at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:274)
  at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:118)
  at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:94)
  ...
```

**UPDATE** Calling code in Scala:

```
  notification = new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sync,
    "%s %s".format(statusTitle, finishedStatus), 0)
  notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
  notification.setLatestEventInfo(SyncService.this, statusTitle, finishedStatus,
    PendingIntent.getActivity(SyncService.this, 0, new Intent(SyncService.this, classOf[MainActivity]), 0))
  notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification)
```

Comment: A little code would be helpful. When are you calling the NotifcationManager? If you are only receiving this from one user, it is possible that it is an isolated incident.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that notification player tries to acquire wake lock when playing sound.

[NotificationManagerService source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java;h=73d17ea7d22d08a331e89786fd3b7ad5367573a4;hb=refs/heads/froyo#l408)

[NotificationPlayer source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=services/java/com/android/server/NotificationPlayer.java;h=52d23810b15ae0791da2f5eefd6e5345b2c6b88a;hb=refs/heads/froyo#l264)

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are using a service. Perhaps the service runs too long and the phone goes back to sleep before the notification could be sent. I assume you're using the AlarmManager to bring the phone out of sleep to check for updates? If that is the case, you are just going to have to declare the `WAKE_LOCK` permission like so:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

I have run into this issue before, especially when updating from services on the internet. The only solution I have found is to declare the `WAKE_LOCK` permission.

Comment: Yes, the service is running long time. But should the notification wake up the phone? It is not specified in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is an issue of some firmwares only, currently the problem has only Meizu.